# How to retrieve all firebase data inside a different date child file

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: This is my firebase.]

The user is creating the data based on the date he chose. So I use the date to separate it so the user can store the data based on the date.  The problem is I want to retrieve all the data and put it all in the listview and show when the app is starting. But I cannot reach the child file which is the date file. So is that anyway I can retrieve all the data inside the user but did not point to the child file?

```
DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");
    Query checkUser = reference.orderByChild("userid").equalTo(uid);

    checkUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){

                String dateFromDB= dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("date").getValue(String.class);
                String weightFromDB= dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("weight").getValue(String.class);

                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), Menu.class);

                intent.putExtra("date", dateFromDB);
                intent.putExtra("weight", weightFromDB);
                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
```

I try to use this code to retrieve but it returns a null value.

Comment: where is the database image?

Comment: sorry, I have updated, please take a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you retrieve the data:

You will have to loop through all the dates IDs and extract the data

```
DatabaseReference reference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("user");

ValueEventListener listener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

     //loop through all the dates
     for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

     //get the data of all the dates
     String date= ds.child("date").getValue(String.class);
     String weight= ds.child("weight").getValue(String.class);

     }

    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());

    }
};
reference.child(uid).addValueEventListener(listener);
```

Comment: Can I put the intent function in the same way I put it? And what is the use of reference.child(uid).addValueEventListener(listener); in the last line?

Comment: I didn't understand the question, but the last line attaches the listener to your reference so that `onDataChange()` will trigger.

Comment: Did you get the data?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, can I know where should I put this function at? Is the function need an onClick listener to trigger it? And where is the retrieved value store now?

Comment: inside the for loop you retrieve all the data of `date` and `weight` you can store them in a string array and pass the arrays by the intent, you can place the above code where ever you want and it should read the data.